# Want to do vlookup with Date range in column wise, getting an error message

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set i = Workbooks("June-2017").Sheets("Daily Match").Range("M12")

Workbooks("June-2017").Sheets("Retail Network").Activate

With ActiveSheet
    If .AutoFilterMode Then AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        'lColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Lr = Worksheets("Retail Network").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Lc = Worksheets("Retail Network").Cells(Columns.Count,"1R").End(xlLeft).Column

        With Range(i & Lr)
            .FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-22],'Credit Pivot'!C[-22]:C[-21],2,0),"" "")"
            ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Set i = considered as Date. Getting an error With Range(i & Lr)
.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-22],'Credit Pivot'!C[-22]:C[-21],2,0),"" "")". I am unable set "i".

Comment: `1` How have you declared i? `2` What is the value of i `3` What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: 1)No. 2)Value of i is Date.3)I am getting an error for  With Range(i & Lr)
            .FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-22],'Credit Pivot'!C[-22]:C[-21],2,0),"" "")"

Comment: Please reread my 3 question and give exact answers. Your answers are very vague. Step though the code to give me the exact value and error message

Comment: Getting an error message "Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed"

Comment: 1) Yes, Set i = Workbooks("June-2017").Sheets("Daily Match").Range("M12")

Comment: 1 question answer is "Yes",

Comment: 2nd question answer is Date range i.e .Range("M12") which i have given on sheet ("Daily Match")